# Is this a typo, or a correct usage of this word?

Tags: persona-gramatical

Mientras leía un texto sobre Rayuela, la novela de Julio Cortázar, llegué a este fragmento:

[image]

En la línea 6, pienso que debería ser `ido` y no `hido`, como sugiere el texto.

Added: Solo para aclarar, si alguien tiene curiosidad, aunque se que lo que agregaré es tal vez totalmente irrelevante al tema principal que es el error ortográfico, pero igual diré, digo que en ese texto se están refiriendo a Lionel Hampton.

Comment: "Hido" podría también ser el participio pasivo del verbo "Her" (hacer, en castellano antiguo), tratándose de un texto de esa época. No dispongo del texto original de Cortázar, por lo que no puedo afirmar si se trata de una mala reconstrucción en el texto de Juan Manuel Bonet o una falta de ortografía.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a typo, it should be 'ido.'